# Валидация на русском языке Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, русификация, auth, kohana

Сделал стандартную регистрацию на сайте, через модуль auth. И решил русифицировать. Все работает, но два лейбла не переводит а именно **password** и **password_confirm**

```
 public function labels(){
       return array('username'=>'поле \'Логин\'',
                    'email'=>'поле \'E-mail\'',
                    'password'=>'поле \'Пароль\'',
                    'password_confirm'=>'поле \'Повтор пароля\''
                    );
   }
```

Специально делаю ошибки. В итоге получаю все на русском кроме пароля и подтверждения.

```
поле 'E-mail' должно быть адресом электронной почты
password не должно быть короче 8 символов
password confirm должно быть как password
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаем папку `ru` в `/application/i18n/`

В созданой папке созаем файл `ru.php`

Пишем в файле переводы, таким образом:

```
return array(
    'login' => 'Логин',
    'email' => 'Email',
    'password' => 'Пароль',
    'confirm' => 'Повтор пароля',
    'captcha' => 'проверочный код'
```

);

Ставим флаг на руский я зык в файле `bootstrap.php`

```
I18n::lang('ru-ru');
```

Comment: А почему так по разному, идет отработка "'username'" - руссифицируем в моделе ("User"), а "'password и 'password_confirm'" в файле по руссификации? К стати с паролями такая штука работает, а вот с "e-mail" - нет. (На локальной машине, руссификацию поля берет с моей модели, а когда сайт залил на другой хост, то все равно с "...\www\modules\orm\classes\Model\Auth\User.php")

Answer (score 0):

В APPPATH/messages/validation.php посмотрите

Comment: Что именно там посмотреть? Именно лейблы не переводятся. 
P.S. Нашел другой способ, сегодня попробую. Если получится, отпишу.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было добавить в каталог modules\account\messages еще один каталог по имени класса extuser\ и уже в нем добавить файл __external.php.

Полный путь должен был выглядеть так:

```
modules\account\messages\extuser\_external.php
```

и в этом файле уже задать массив с лейблами.